# Hybridauth module social network icons not working with user/register page drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, social-networking, hybridauth

```
Hybridauth module social network icons not working with 
Registartion page (user/register) page drupal 6. And it is working with 
User login form (/user) page. Permissions were given to anonymous user too. 

In 'other settings' enabled drupal forms: 
User login form
User login block
User registration form
```

Am i missing anything more. 
Can any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can any one help me. Struggling since a week. Its very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the module code - https://drupal.org/node/1990788 - already fixed in the dev version.